# GROUPBY with showing all the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to do a groupby of my MODELS by CITYS with keeping all the columns where i can print the percentage of each MODELS IN THIS CITY. 
I put my dataframe in PHOTO below.

And i have written this code but i don"t know how to do ??

`for name,group in d_copy.groupby(['CITYS'])['MODELS']:`

Comment: You need to include a sample of your dataframe, as well as your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this : `d_copy.groupby(['CITYS','MODELS']).mean()` to have the average percentage of a model by city.

Then if you want to catch the percentages you have to convert it in DF and select the column : `pd.DataFrame(d_copy.groupby(['CITYS','MODELS']).mean())['PERCENTAGE']`

Answer (score 0):

You can group by and then print each group.

```
df_group=df.groupby(['CITYS'])
for key,value in df_group:
    print(value)
```